# KSH: using sed to return text to the right of a pattern

Tags: sed, ksh

All,

I'm trying to write a KSH script using sed (I'm very new to ksh) that pulls this SQL query from a log, but I want it to ignore the time stamp and the six characters/spaces that follow it.  Here's the code that I have so far...

```
cat file.log \
| sed -n '/---Query1/,/selected/p' \
| sed 's/^([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]??????)//g' \    # My problem
> newfile.log

===Input===

11:23:34 SQL> ---Query1    
11:23:34 SQL> select a.column1, b.column2, count(*)
11:23:34   2  from table1 a, table2 b
11:23:34   3  group by a.column1
11:23:34   4  order by 1, 2, 3;

a.column1   a.column2   count(*)
----------- ----------- ----------
foo         bar         32

1 row selected.


===Desired Output===

---Query1
select a.column1, b.column2, count(*)
from table1 a, table2 b
group by a.column1
order by 1, 2, 3;

a.column1   a.column2   count(*)
----------- ----------- ----------
foo         bar         32

1 row selected.
```

Any help you can offer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 for sample input/output AND code. Keep posting and good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -r 's/^..:..:...{6}//' file
```

Answer (score 2):

"?" in a regular expression means "zero or 1 occurrences of the preceding RE segment" so when you write:

```
[0-9]?
```

you're saying "zero or 1 occurrences of a digit". I suspect you're getting the meaning of "?" in an RE confused with what it means in shell globbing which is "any single character". The RE metacharacter that means "any single character" is ".", not "?".

SO I think when you wrote:

```
sed 's/^([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]??????)//g'
```

you actually intended to write:

```
sed 's/^([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]......)//g'
```

which you can abbreviate to:

```
sed 's/^([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]??????)//g'
```

With some (e.g. GNU) sed's you can write ".{6}" instead of 6 explicit "."s.

Note that you do not need the "cat" and that if you put the pipe at the end of each line instead of at the start of the next one then you don't need the escaping backslashes either. You also don't need the parens around your RE since you never back-reference or otherwise use it e.g.:

```
sed -n '/---Query1/,/selected/p' file.log |
sed 's/^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]......//g' > newfile.log
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, and thank you for the lesson.  I cracked open my first KSH book about two weeks ago, so I'm trying to absorb anything I can right now.

Comment: THE most important thing to understand about shell is that while it has programming language constructs (if, while, etc.) it is NOT intended as programming language. It is an environment from which to invoke tools. Usually if you find yourself writing a loop in shell you are missing the point and there's a tool better suited for the job. The exceptions being when you are creating/destroying/waiting-for processes or creating/removing/moving files. So read a shell book if you like but invest a lot more time learning the tools you call from the shell, with awk being the biggest bang for the buck.

Answer (score 1):

just did a little test on your example data, it worked here:

```
 sed -r '/^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/{s/^.*SQL> *//;s/^[0-9:]* +[0-9]+ +(.)/\1/}' file
```